# How can we reach to Key/value pairs after group by function on Gremlin?

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3

I have a simple gremlin query, first of all, I aggregate data, then I want to reach aggregated data and I want to use it on other operations. But after group-by operation, I couldn’t reach them as key/value pair.

```
GraphTraversal t = graph.V().hasLabel("App").as("a")
        .inE("RANKS").as("r")
        .outV().as("k")
        .choose(__.select("k").by("countryCode").is(__.in(...)),
                __.math("1.0 / r").by("rank1"),
                __.math("1.0 / r").by("rank2"))
        .as("score")
            .select("a").aggregate("ap")
            .select("k").by("countryCode").aggregate("country")
    .select("a", "k").by("appId").by("countryCode")
                .group().by("grp_res").by(__.select("score").sum().as("sum_score"))
                .cap("ap", "country", "grp_res")
               .V().hasLabel("App").where(P.within("ap")).as("app")
               .select("app", "country", "ak").by("appId").by().by();
```

The last line `.select("app", "ak").by("appId").by()` couldn’t be reachable askey/value pair after group-by. How can I reach them? Do you have any suggestion?

Now it looks:

```
{app=1, country=US, ak={{a=1, k=US}=363.0, {a=2, k=US}=544.5}}
{app=2, country=US, ak={{a=1, k=US}=363.0, {a=2, k=US}=544.5}}
```

But expected output is:

```
{app=1, country=US, ak=363.0}
{app=2, country=US, ak=544.5}
```

**Solved like:**

```
group().by(...)
.select(Column.values).as("grp_result")
.select("grp_result").select("score").as("score")
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you define "ak" in your query but the basic issue is that you have nested maps where the keys are themselves a map. So you will need to select from the map using that exact key or order the groups differently to have simpler keys. Then would do something like `select('ak').select('key')`.